# How to execute two different functions concurrently in Python?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I have two different functions (`funcA` and `funcB`) that I want to be executed concurrently to cut down on overall execution time.

`funcA` is an API call that takes somewhere between 5 to 7 seconds.

`funcB` is a CPU intensive operation that uses ML algorithms and takes somewhere between 7 to 10 seconds.

A simple dummy version of `funcA` and `funcB` would be:

```py
def funcA(inpA):
    res1 = apiCall1(inpA)
    res2 = apiCall2(res1)
    if res2['requireAPICall3']:
        res3 = apiCall3(res2)
        return res3
    else:
        return res2
```

```py
def funcB(inpB):
    modelPath = downloadModel()
    model = loadModel(modelPath)
    prediction = predict(inpB)
    return prediction
```

#### For context:

This will all be done on a python server.

The request will contain two parts, let's say `inpA` and `inpB`. `inpA` will be passed to `funcA` and `inpB` will be passed to `funcB`.

Currently the overall execution is as follows:

```py
def processRequest(request):
    response = {}
    response['outA'] = funcA(request['inpA'])
    response['outB'] = funcB(request['inpB'])
    return response
```

So, the overall execution takes somewhere between 12 to 17 seconds.
But considering both the functions take separate input and are not dependent on each other if they could be executed simultaneously, the overall request would take much less time (7 to 10 seconds for this example).

Every function being used is synchronous. I can make `funcA` async but making `funcB` async is not an option right now. Maybe it can be wrapped in an `async` function. I'm not totally sure about asynchronous programming in Python so any help would be greatly appreciated. Maybe `multithreading` can be an option as well.

I tried using `asyncio` library and it's `gather` function. But for some reason, it worked the same as the `processRequest` function described above.

Below is the code I tried using `asyncio`:

```py
async def funcA(inpA):
    return apiCall(inpA)

async def funcB(inpB):
    return predict(inpB)

async def processRequest(req):
    t1 = asyncio.create_task(funcA(req['inpA']))
    t2 = asyncio.create_task(funcB(req['inpB']))
    return await asyncio.gather(t1, t2)
```

I updated the `apiCall` function as below to test Anentropic's Answer.

```py
async def apiCall(inpA):
    res1 = await apiCall1(inpA)
    res2 = await apiCall2(res1)
    if res2['requireAPICall3']:
        res3 = await apiCall3(res2)
        return res3
    else:
        return res2
```

Comment: For concurrency/parallelism in Python, you typically have two options (which you seem to know already, given the tags on this question): Multithreading and Multiprocessing. Which one you choose depends on the needs of your project, but I **<OPINION>** tend to use threading because I find it easier **</OPINION>**. For either approach, you'll need to use something like a `Queue` to get values back to the main thread/process. You could also look into `ThreadPoolExecutor` or `ProcessPoolExecutor`, either of which may suit here.

Comment: This sounds entirely possible, in theory you should be able to call `funcA` asynchronously and then `funcB` should be able to do most of its CPU intensive work while `funcA` is waiting for API response. Maybe it would help to show us the code you tried for asyncio

Comment: @Anentropic I have added the code I tried using asyncio in the question

Comment: Yes, but what code is in `apiCall()` and `predict()`? These are just aliases for `funcA` and `funcB`.

Comment: @JRiggles How should I figure out what's the best way to use in this case?

Comment: `asyncio` won't help CPU-intensive tasks. It's only useful for IO-waiting tasks.

Comment: @quamrana As mentioned in the question, `apiCall()` is just an api call to another server to fetch some data, and `predict()` function is basically downloading the model files, loading the model, running prediction on the input and returning the output

Comment: @eNeM I suppose the short answer is: try both and see which performs better for your use case.

Comment: @Shuai Can `asyncio` not be used or is it not preferred to use it?

Comment: @eNeM It is not suitable. Async functions (or coroutines) allow the thread to suspend current task and switch to another task if it need to wait for a IO result. If your task is not IO-bound, your thread won't wait, then it won't benefit from "suspend and switch to another task".

Comment: @Shuai Thanks for the insight. But can it be done in the way Anentropic mentioned above in comments

Comment: asyncio uses a single thread. It will only switch between tasks on specific await boundaries. if you have a long task that doesn't ever wait on anything, it will block any other async tasks from running. This can cause other i/o tasks that have been scheduled but not run to timeout. If you have a long running task, it should periodically do something like `await asyncio.sleep(0)` to let other tasks run.

Comment: You seem to be making a sync function async with `async def funcB(inpB):`. But that causes the entire async task quue to wait until that sync function is done. If its just CPU bound, then it may be okay, but if it is doing any i/o, including reading from disk, it wrecks performance.

Comment: @JRiggles What other ways are there to achieve multithreading/multiprocessing without using `ThreadPoolExecutor` or `ProcessPoolExecutor`? And how is multithreading easier than multiprocessing? Is it code implementation wise?  I think I should also read and learn what's the differences between multiprocessing and multithreading performance wise.

Comment: @tdelaney I think I might have hit the problem you mentioned because of making a sync function async. Because once the sync function starts executing the whole async function goes to a halt till the sync function is over. What would you suggest to overcome this problem?

Comment: @eNeM - It depends on what the function does. If its a pure-cpu calculation, you could move it to a background thread or, if its input and output are relatively small, a separate process. I've done async-like programming where we needed to insert sleeps in our algorithms to keep other tasks running - but that's best avoided when possible. If it does i/o like reading files, then the whole function could be moved to async versions of file i/o.

Comment: @eNeM You could also use `threading.Thread` or `multiprocessing.Process` in lieu of their "pool" counterparts. For ether implementation, the respective API for threading vs. multiprocessing is very similar, but multiprocessing comes with some caveats when it comes to passing data back and forth between processes.

Comment: @tdelaney I have added a basic idea of what the functions do in the question. It involves downloading huge models from cloud storage, loading them, and running predictions on them.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ProcessPoolExecutor` from the [`concurrent.futures`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) module of Python.

I wrote a simple demo for your problem:

```py
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
import time
from time import sleep

def funcA(x):
    sleep(7)  # simulate a long running task
    return x * x

def funcB(y):
    sleep(10)  # simulate a long running task
    return y + y

# the global executor
executor = ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=2)

def main(x, y):
    res = []
    start = time.time()

    # submit the tasks
    task_A = executor.submit(funcA, x)
    task_B = executor.submit(funcB, y)

    # wait for the tasks to complete
    res.append(task_A.result())
    res.append(task_B.result())

    end = time.time()
    print("Time taken: {}".format(end - start))

    return res

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(main(2, 3))
```

Output:

```
Time taken: 10.005340814590454
[4, 6]
```

It took ~10s to finish a 7s Task-A and a 10s Task-B.

---

I prefer `ProcessPoolExecutor` over `ThreadPoolExecutor` because:

> `ProcessPoolExecutor` uses the `multiprocessing` module, which allows it to side-step the [Global Interpreter Lock](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-global-interpreter-lock) but also means that only picklable objects can be executed and returned.

Comment: Note that using `ProcessPoolExecutor` is what allows the blocking `time.sleep` calls to run concurrently here. Which is great! However it is using `multiprocessing` which means there is a serialization boundary when sending arguments into and getting return value from the task functions. If you have a large complicated return value this de/serialization is extra CPU work which has to be done in both the parent and task processes. This may be an unnecessary overhead in OP case where one function is specifically an API request that can be run asynchronously (waits for IO).

Comment: So if I had to use multithreading instead of multiprocessing, the only change I would need to make to the code is replace `ProcessPoolExecutor` with `ThreadPoolExecutor`?

Answer (score 1):

As long as the code in `apiCall` is fully async (i.e. you are using an async lib to make the API requests such as https://www.python-httpx.org/async/) then this pattern should work:

```py
import asyncio
import time

async def api_call():
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    return "A"

async def funcA():
    return await api_call()

async def funcB():
    time.sleep(3)
    return "B"

async def process():
    start = time.time()
    t1, t2 = await asyncio.gather(funcA(), funcB())
    end = time.time()
    print(f"elapsed: {end - start}s")
    return t1, t2

result = asyncio.run(process())
print(result)
```

For purposes of a demo I have used `time.sleep` in funcB as a non-async (blocking) call, representing your CPU-intensive operation, and `asyncio.sleep` in funcA as a non-blocking call representing your API request.

If you run this code you should see 3s elapsed instead of 6s.

If you substitute `time.sleep` for the `asyncio.sleep` you will find that it takes 6s, indicating that any blocking code in the async functions will obstruct your concurrency.

Comment: Will it work if I make it with the `aiohttp` package?

Comment: @eNeM yes definitely, that's an async library, so just make an `async def` function with that lib which returns the result of an `await`ed call and you should be fine

Comment: I tried this method with a change: funcA was the API call using a fully `aiohttp` and all async functions, `funcB` was another API call using sync method. The output was not how I expected it to be. Both the functions were called together at the start but once it got to the point of API call, the `funcB` (sync) executed first and the actual execution (API call) of `funcA` (async) started after funcB was completed. This behavior seems weird to me. I will try with the original `predict` function tomorrow and let you know how that works. Meanwhile, can you explain the behavior that happened here?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing exact code. CPU-intensive work and async don't mix well together. Perhaps the demo code in my answer was "lucky" somehow and in practice this pattern is fragile, i.e. we rely on `funcA` getting as far as making the API request before its `await` call allows the async event loop to task switch to `funcB`... the loop can task switch at any `await`, but if it happens too early then the non-async blocking call in `funcB` will happen first.